# How do I collapse all extended blocks?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use this collapsible menu. I want to be able to collapse all blocks under the collapsible menu under the header block. Currently, they all keep extended.

The script for the extension of the block -

```
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

I'd like all extended blocks under the header block to re-collapse once the header block is clicked on again.

Comment: can you show your html code?

Comment: Add `Array.from(coll).forEach(x => x.classList.remove('active'))` before `this.classList.toggle("active");`.